# Evenly Spread WebApp DB Connections to SQL Server VMs

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I'm in the process of migrating an existing website into Azure for a client. The current architecture is 4 web vm's mated to 4 sql server vms. One web vm per sql server vm. Complexity and cost is prohibiting us from migrating the sql server vm's into azure sql servers. These are read only databases and use log shipping to keep them synced.

I have easily published the asp.net application to an azure web app. My question is, how do I evenly distribute the web app instances to the 4 sql server vm's?

Depending on hourly traffic, I can see anywhere from 2 to 8 web app instances running at any given time. How can I evenly distribute the load to the 4 database vm's?

Comment: on onprem,how were you able to keep the databases in sync ?

Comment: log shipping to a set of hot and cold databases. Once all the colds have been updated, we switch them and the hots becomes the colds and begin getting updated with the latest changes from a non web facing "master" database.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you setup your environment you could put an [Azure Internal Load Balancer (ILB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-internal-overview) in place to load balance TCP 1433 across the four back-end SQL Database Servers.

You might need to tweak the [distribution mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-distribution-mode), but I'd run it first to see what the performance is like. If the Database is relatively static perhaps you could even consider using a VM Scale Set to scale out SQL based on load.

Comment: Any concerns regarding connection pooling. Will throwing a LB in front of the DB servers wreak havoc with the underlying connection pooling?

Comment: I haven't tried your scenario specifically. I'd say that as long as the distribution mode was set to ensure clients remain conected to a specific SQL server you should see no impact. The beauty of something like Azure is you could do a quick proof-of-concept to confirm behaviour before you migrate to this model.